# The clang equivalent for the gcc -O

Tags: gcc, clang

How to do in clang the gcc -O optimizing option equivalent?

`gcc -O3 -o tes  tes.cpp`

on clang ...?

Comment: clang is compatible so `-O3` works. What are you asking?

Comment: clang also allows `-Wall`, just like gcc, meaning "show me all the warnings which I almost certainly need to attend to". If you use `-Wextra` and `-pedantic` with gcc, clang does them as well.

Comment: And, by the way,  [tag:compiler-construction] is for questions about writing compilers, not about using them.

Comment: Why do you assume it's different?

Answer (score 0):

You do exactly the same.

```
clang -O3 -o tes tes.cpp
```